# How to customize transition of MVVM light navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I am trying to customize the transition of navigation in MVVM but I couldn't find any

In iOS we can show it as modal,popup etc

So far in my search I couldn't find any way to customize the transition

If possible i would like to remove the transition and make it appear.

Any help is good